# how to check if script running in virtualenv accesses global python

Tags: python, virtualenv, sudo

I have large python script `script.py` and I can run it successfully in virtualenv.

```
(virtualenv) user@host:~$ python script.py
```

But when I want to run it as sudo, I use virtualenv's python path.

```
(virtualenv) user@host:~$ <path-to-virtualenv>/bin/python script.py
```

But this raises error. I have a doubt that it is accessing some global python package. Is there a way to check if running script/app is accessing global python packages or not.

[note] script is so large that I could not debug it line-by-line.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is very much app specific but traceback traces through virtualenv python packages. But I guess something wrong happens before reaching to error point and that wrong might have happened due to global python packages. By the way, there are many packages common in my global and virtualenv. They differ in versions.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's impossible to figure out what's happening without knowing the error.

Comment: What is the specific error message?  If it identifies a line of code which causes the error, what is the source code of that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the trace module as found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

Run it as:

```
<path to virtualenv>/python -m trace filetoexec.py
```

There are lots of options with trace to see what a file is doing, the -t option dumps everything out line by line, you can see what modules are being imported from where.